# Obtaining the tails of different lengths from sub-lists

Tags: r, list, tail

My problem is that I have a list with sub-lists and I want to obtain the tails of each sub-list, but these should be of different sizes.

For example, I would like to get the tail of length n=10 for sub-list **a** and the tail of length n=5 for sub-list **b** (see code below). How to best do this?

myList <- list(list(a=replicate(10, rnorm(20)), b=replicate(10, rnorm(10))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myTail <- c(10, 5)
lapply(1:length(myTail), function(x) tail(unlist(myList[[1]][x]), myTail[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your list creation query. Please have a look.

```
myList <- list(a=replicate(10, rnorm(20)), b=replicate(10, rnorm(10)))
lapply(myList, tail, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Luca. This helps. I looked around and found a purrr function (map2) which makes this easier to do. I'll add it for the benefit of anyone searching for a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found this solution using the package purrr

library(purrr)

myList <- list(a=replicate(10, rnorm(20)), b=replicate(10, rnorm(10)))

Tail <- list(10, 5)

MyTail <- map2(myList, Tail, `tail`)

Thanks for the suggestions!